# How to embed an Excel file on a website through HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a restaurant menu in an Excel file and I need to insert it into HTML but I don't know how to do it. If anyone has a better idea or knows how to do it please reply. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide an example excel file?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/embed-your-excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-sharepoint-or-onedrive-for-business-7af74ce6-e8a0-48ac-ba3b-a1dd627b7773

Comment: I would rather copy the infos from the excel file and create a simple static web page.

Comment: Thank you for your solutions to my problem. I tried all of them and they worked.